# JDBI: Inserting Dates as longs (milliseconds)

Tags: java, date, jdbi

In my application I store dates as milliseconds

```
public class Model {
    private long date = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public void setDate(long date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public long getDate() {
        return date;
    }
}
```

I have a JDBI Data Access Object which looks like:

```
public interface ModelDAO {

    @SqlBatch("REPLACE INTO model (date) VALUES (:date)")
    @BatchChunkSize(1000)
    void insertModels(@BindBean List<Model> models);

    @SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM model ORDER BY date DESC")
    List<Model> getModels();
}
```

However when I try to insert I get:

> org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToExecuteStatementException:
>   java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime
>   value: '1430262000000' for column 'date'

Is there a way I can tell JDBI how to convert this without requiring something like the below for all my classes with dates in?

```
@BindingAnnotation(BindModel.ModelBindingFactor.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface BindModel {

    public static class ModelBindingFactor implements BinderFactory {
        public Binder build(Annotation annotation) {
            return new Binder<BindModel, Model>() {
                public void bind(SQLStatement q, BindModel bind, Model model) {
                    q.bind("date", new Timestamp(model.getDate()));
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I would be willing to switch my models to use a DateTime object if it makes things cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

It will be easier and more cleaner if you can use DateTime to store date values. You should have a argumentFactory to convert DateTime to sql date. You can use the following one.

```
public class DateTimeAsSqlDateArgument implements ArgumentFactory<DateTime> {

    @Override
        public boolean accepts(Class<?> expectedType, Object value, StatementContext ctx) {
            return value != null && DateTime.class.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass());
        }

        @Override
        public Argument build(Class<?> expectedType, final DateTime value, StatementContext ctx) {
            return new Argument() {
                @Override
                public void apply(int position, PreparedStatement statement, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {
                    statement.setTimestamp(position, new Timestamp(value.getMillis()));
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Register this argument factory to dbi. That's all you need. JDBI will use this factory whenever it see DateTime object.

```
dbi.registerArgumentFactory(new DateTimeAsSqlDateArgument());
```